# How to intercept stdout from Python shell exec using subprocess.call?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, exec, subprocess

I want to create a function that will return output of a shell, I have something like this:

```
def shell_exec(code):
    buff = StringIO.StringIO()
    subprocess.call(code, shell=True, stdout=buff)
    return buff.getvalue()
```

but got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in shell_exec
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 703, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1115, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). It returns command output.

```
def shell_exec(code):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(code, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return e.output
```

BTW, valid values for `stdin`,`stdout`,`stderr` are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`.

Comment: Why did you remove `shell=True`? Can you write it as a function with that key as before?

Comment: @jcubic, Sorry, it was removed by accident. I meant to remove only `stdout=..`. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing that.